# Bypassing custom Model Manager to get ManyToMany objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a maintenance project which has a model say Business with a custom Model Manager. This custom Model Manager adds some extra filter to all the queries executing on Business models. This Business model has a ManyToMany field to self named Trainers. So far so good, the issue comes in when I try to fetch all the Trainers associated with the Business without applying those filters.

The Business model is as given below:

```
class Business(Basetable):
    #status P=publish    H=inactive    D=draft    N=new
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    logo=models.OneToOneField("BusinessLogo",null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("BusinessCategory",related_name='allcategories',null=True)
    price_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=PRICE_CHOICES,
                                      default=YEARLY, null=True, blank=True)
    achievements = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    years_of_experience = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    trainers = models.ManyToManyField("self",related_name='btrainers',null=True, blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    expense=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    objects= CityManager()

    def get_trainers(self):
      return self.trainers.all()
```

`get_trainers` is the function which returns all the Trainers associated with the Business, however I want the results to bypass the `CityManager` and use the default Manager.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

**Update:**

using `use_for_related_fields = False` does not work. I found a related [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14891) here. Is there a work around? I know that overriding the default `objects` is not a good practice, however this is what I have received.

Comment: I don't know of a real solution off the top of my head, but a nasty terrible solution would be to have a flag on your manager that you set to False in get_trainers.

Comment: Why don't you set my_objects= CityManager() and use objects as default

Comment: Couldn't you try to directly access the table that represents the ManyToManyField in the database (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#id1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's better to [avoid filtering results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#default-managers) in the default `Manager`:

> It's a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding `get_queryset()` results in an inability to retrieve objects you'd like to work with.

But if you can't change the default `Manager` for backwards-compatibility reasons, you can still explicitly create a plain `Manager` and get your results using that.

```
class Business(Basetable):
    ...
    objects = CityManager()  # Still the first listed, and default
    plain_objects = models.Manager()
```

Now that you have a plain `Manager`, use it to explicitly access the desired objects:

```
def get_trainers(self):
    return Business.plain_objects.filter(btrainers__id=self.id)
```

Comment: Upvoted as given the "default manager must not change" constraint, this is the best option that comes to my mind. But really, for anyone else stumbling upon this, it should be the other way around: default manager should return all, and custom managers should be used for filtering.